# Get urls of all open tabs in chrome, and send it to a web service

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension to get urls of all open tabs and save them all to send them to a domain.so i require 2 steps:

1. Get urls of all open tabs and store them in an array or stuff like
   that.
2. Send the array of all urls to a domain.

Comment: I'm guessing by the votes I'm not the only one who thinks this sounds dodgy...

Comment: This question has an answer that explains how to find all the open tab URLs using Javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915370/retrieving-which-tabs-are-open-in-chrome

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at [`chrome.windows.getAll`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-getAll) to get a list of open windows. Each window has a `tabs` property that contains a list of tabs in the window. Each tab has a `url` property. See [tabs documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab).

You'll want to loop over the windows, and then the tabs in each window, and add these to your array and then do whatever it is you want to do.

Normally you can't do this, but chrome extensions with the necessary permissions are allowed to do [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html). You'll need that to send the list to the other domain.

You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert an array to a string that you can send and then some similar function on the server side to convert it back to an array.

Comment: Use `XMLHttpRequest` to send the list of URLs to a "domain".