# avoid opening extra window/tab by checking whether browser tab is already opened

Tags: jquery

Am trying the below case using jquery

Is there any way to check all the windows/tabs opened in the browser (IE) and open a link in same window in order to avoid multiple windows i.e.
say i have a window which has links

a,b,c where a (link=google/abc) b (link=google/def) c (link=google/xyz)

the code should check only if the link starts with google in above link and open a window/tab in the same tab where the address starts with google

I am trying with the below code

```
window.open(url, "windowName")
```

but the above approach will only work if i open the window using window.open and keep a reference as windowName. Is there any other way other than this?

Comment: I think this Question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114395/get-urls-of-all-open-tabs-in-chrome-and-send-it-to-a-web-service

Comment: I think its only with respect to chrome and it wont open window

Comment: I don't think this is possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553334/how-to-get-the-url-of-currently-opened-tabs-in-all-browsers-with-php-or-javascri