# Background scripts vs Content Scripts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to develop a chrome extension which saves the url of webpages opened in all tabs and then load them whenever needed. Now I know content scripts, background scripts and popup.js. Content scripts mainly deal with the content of the loaded webpage and they have less chrome api interactions, background scripts are executed in an isolated environment and we can use all chrome api methods, popup.js is simply javascript that runs in context of popup.html.

Now here is my problem, I have a button in popup.html named "save" and on click of that button I want to save all the webpage urls opened in multiple tabs under one window. How can I do that? 
Should I write a content or a background script?

Sorry for my noobish question. I am new to chrome api. Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get urls of all open tabs in chrome, and send it to a web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114395/get-urls-of-all-open-tabs-in-chrome-and-send-it-to-a-web-service)

Comment: @Ghostship No actually. Read the full question. I know the title is same, i will rephrase it.

Comment: first, read the documentation about messaging and how to communicate between popup and background. other questions already answer that communication part. do not ask friends to upvote, that just draws more attention from moderators like me.

Comment: @ZigMandel Thanks for the help. Sorry, but I didn't ask anyone to upvote my post. Even if you think I did, I am sorry.

Comment: Well, you have more or less already answered your question within the Question. Do you need access to the content of the webpages to do what you want (content script)? Do you need access the the full Chrome API to do what you want (background script)? Do you need either? Does your code within your popup have sufficient access to the APIs and information to do what you desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither content script or background page is needed. You could do that just in `popup.js`, since popup page actually runs in the same context with extension.

In your `popup.js`, just call [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) to get tab info, including url (you would need to declare `tabs` permissions in `manifest.json`). If you want to specify window id, either use [`WINDOW_ID_CURRENT`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#property-WINDOW_ID_CURRENT) or retrieve it through other ways (depends on your logic)

```
chrome.tabs.query({ windowId: YOUR_WINDOW_ID }, (tabs) => {
    tabs.forEach((tab) => console.log(tab.url));
});
```